# Error using SoapClient in PHP and AMPPS on OS X

Tags: php, macos, soap, https, wsdl

I have installed AMPPS on OS X Mavericks and I am getting the error below when I try to access a WSDL over HTTPS in PHP by using the `SoapClient` class.

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://www.some-domain.com/Webservice.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load
>   external entity
>   "https://www.some-domain.com/secure/api/Webservice.asmx?WSDL"

OpenSSL, SOAP and cURL is enabled in when I run `phpinfo()`. I can retrieve the WSDL contents just fine by using `file_get_contents()`. There is no firewall blocking the connection. Other computers on the same network can connect just fine. Below is my code. It works on the production server as well as several other computers that I have used it on.

```
$this->wsdlUrl = 'https://www.some-domain.com/Webservice.asmx?WSDL';
$this->client = new SoapClient($this->wsdlUrl);
$this->client->Connect(array(
    /* Login credentials */
));
```

I have also tried to use a stream context with `verify_peer` set to `false`, but with the same result. Increasing the `default_socket_timeout` option also does not work as some people have suggested.

I understand that there are several other questions concerning this error, but none of the proposed solutions that I could find work for me.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like AMPPS doesn't have php_openssl exentsion so you couldn't use SOAP with HTTPS

Comment: @Andy, did you reach to any solution?  I am also having same problem, and specifically with AMPPS on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this will point you to the right direction:

```
try {
    $sc= new SoapClient('https://www.some-domain.com/Webservice.asmx?WSDL');
    $sc->Connect(/* Login credentials */);
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    print_r($fault->faultstring);
}
```

Comment: That gives exactly the same error message as the one in the question.